# Unable to establish connection from c# app to node.js using client certificate

Tags: c#, ssl

I have a C# application, that connects to local node.js simulator over TLS using client certificate.
I've succesfully connected to simulator via firefox, so my assumption it's working correctly.
However when I try to connect from application every time exception is being thrown:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> 
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

I've enabled tracing by adding to app.config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true" />
  <sources>
    <source name="System.Net" maxdatasize="1024">
      <listeners>
        <add name="MyTraceFile"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="MyTraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="System.Net.trace.log" />
  </sharedListeners>
  <switches>
    <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

And the contents of trace file with every connection looks like:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [3176] Current OS installation type is 'Client'.
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [6388] HttpWebRequest#26277487::HttpWebRequest(https://127.0.0.1:9443/redfish/v1#-1567912745)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [6388] Exiting HttpWebRequest#26277487::HttpWebRequest() 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [6388] HttpWebRequest#26277487::HttpWebRequest(uri: 'https://127.0.0.1:9443/redfish/v1', connectionGroupName: '52919584')
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [6388] Exiting HttpWebRequest#26277487::HttpWebRequest() 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [6388] ServicePoint#10100579::ServicePoint(127.0.0.1:9443)
System.Net Information: 0 : [6388] Associating HttpWebRequest#26277487 with ServicePoint#10100579
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [6072] HttpWebRequest#26277487::BeginGetResponse()
System.Net Information: 0 : [6072] Associating Connection#22724141 with HttpWebRequest#26277487
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [6072] Exiting HttpWebRequest#26277487::BeginGetResponse()  -> ContextAwareResult#61012356
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] Connection#22724141 - Created connection from 127.0.0.1:61743 to 127.0.0.1:9443.
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] TlsStream#21173642::.ctor(host=127.0.0.1, #certs=1)
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] Associating HttpWebRequest#26277487 with ConnectStream#2172044
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] HttpWebRequest#26277487 - Request: GET /redfish/v1 HTTP/1.1

System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] ConnectStream#2172044 - Sending headers
{
Host: 127.0.0.1:9443
Connection: Keep-Alive
}.
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] SecureChannel#24341498::.ctor(hostname=127.0.0.1, #clientCertificates=1, encryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] Enumerating security packages:
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276]     Negotiate
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276]     NegoExtender
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276]     Kerberos
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276]     NTLM
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276]     TSSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276]     pku2u
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276]     LiveSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276]     WDigest
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276]     Schannel
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276]     Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276]     CREDSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] SecureChannel#24341498 - Attempting to restart the session using the user-provided certificate: [Version]
  V1

[Subject]
  C=PL, S=Pomorskie, L=GDN, O=Company, CN=localhost
  Simple Name: localhost
  DNS Name: localhost

[Issuer]
  CN=localhost, O=Company, L=GDN, S=3City, C=PL
  Simple Name: localhost
  DNS Name: localhost

[Serial Number]
  00DA4A8EB63CBBF520

[Not Before]
  2015-12-15 10:09:14

[Not After]
  2018-06-02 11:09:14

[Thumbprint]
  57A9E63FFBE670739443ACFC3D2A1879B894769D

[Signature Algorithm]
  sha256ECDSA(1.2.840.10045.4.3.2)

[Public Key]
  Algorithm: ECC
  Key Blob: 04 88 a8 fc be ad 02 6c 48 68 42 11 4c 03 87 f9 e6 fb 4c 74 97 e2 0b 13 5a 09 c2 62 3f 15 a2 ac b1 7f 24 d0 d5 97 37 cb 85 79 12 e9 71 13 ab e7 8e ef 79 ec d7 c5 dc b9 6c a6 2b d5 c1 e7 c4 77 08
  Parameters: 06 08 2a 86 48 ce 3d 03 01 07

[Private Key]
  Key Store: User
  Provider Name: Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
  Provider type: 0
  Key Spec: 0
  Key Container Name: {216ECC81-B114-48F9-AA62-0A1FE8B2ECDB}
.
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] SecureChannel#24341498 - Left with 1 client certificates to choose from.
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] SecureChannel#24341498 - Trying to find a matching certificate in the certificate store.
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] SecureChannel#24341498 - Locating the private key for the certificate: [Version]
  V1

[Subject]
  C=PL, S=Pomorskie, L=GDN, O=Company, CN=localhost
  Simple Name: localhost
  DNS Name: localhost

[Issuer]
  CN=localhost, O=Company, L=GDN, S=3City, C=PL
  Simple Name: localhost
  DNS Name: localhost

[Serial Number]
  00DA4A8EB63CBBF520

[Not Before]
  2015-12-15 10:09:14

[Not After]
  2018-06-02 11:09:14

[Thumbprint]
  57A9E63FFBE670739443ACFC3D2A1879B894769D

[Signature Algorithm]
  sha256ECDSA(1.2.840.10045.4.3.2)

[Public Key]
  Algorithm: ECC
  Key Blob: 04 88 a8 fc be ad 02 6c 48 68 42 11 4c 03 87 f9 e6 fb 4c 74 97 e2 0b 13 5a 09 c2 62 3f 15 a2 ac b1 7f 24 d0 d5 97 37 cb 85 79 12 e9 71 13 ab e7 8e ef 79 ec d7 c5 dc b9 6c a6 2b d5 c1 e7 c4 77 08
  Parameters: 06 08 2a 86 48 ce 3d 03 01 07

[Private Key]
  Key Store: User
  Provider Name: Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
  Provider type: 0
  Key Spec: 0
  Key Container Name: {216ECC81-B114-48F9-AA62-0A1FE8B2ECDB}
.
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] SecureChannel#24341498 - Certificate is of type X509Certificate2 and contains the private key.
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc     = System.Net.SecureCredential)
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = (null), targetName = 127.0.0.1, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffer length=0, Out-Buffer length=137, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 58f20568b0:5d9d6c7de0, targetName = 127.0.0.1, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [8276] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=IllegalMessage).
System.Net Error: 0 : [8276] Exception in HttpWebRequest#26277487:: - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [8276] HttpWebRequest#26277487::EndGetResponse()
System.Net Error: 0 : [8276] Exception in HttpWebRequest#26277487::EndGetResponse - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
```

The message returned code=ContinueNeeded appeared as if 100 Continue Code was being returned and upon researching a bit I've added following line:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

However, it didn't fix the problem, so I'm back to square one, with only information being that **returned code=IllegalMessage**
So my question is: what do I do wrong?

Comment: I found the error code that corresponds to `IllegalMessage` in the Microsoft reference source. It's 0x80090326. You might want to try searching for that to see if it's helpful. For example, this may be relevant: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/d63c142c-c408-43be-9ffc-8096d1aff3cb/decrypt-failed-with-error-0x80090326

Comment: A little feedback. I'm unable to connect to simulator using other browsers!. I've tried Internet Explorer and Chrome and failed. Firefox tells me that it established TLS 1.2 connection. IE tells me, that:

This page can't be displayed Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to https://localhost:9443  again. If this error persists, contact your site administrator. (Checked and all 3 versions of TLS are enabled)

Chrome says: 
This webpage is not available
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
...this site uses an unsupported protocol

Comment: It sounds like the server's cipher offers are unacceptable. Use OpenSSL tools to find out what the server's cipher offers are, and ensure that they include at least one which the client can use, e.g. RSA/AES/SHA.

Comment: @Ben you were right. There were some pretty unusual ciphers set for this node.js application (to be exact only one). I will answer this question with solution that worked for us, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction.